# Non-responsive bootstrap design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My scenario is

I want to my app to be responsive if width is more than 1024px.

If user is playing with browser and if he hits below the 1024px mark, I want the app to be non-responsive and want horizontal scroll bar.

I tried to place `min-width` in the body tag and it is still responsive below 1024px.

How can I do this ?

```
<body style="min-width: 1300px">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #f5f5f5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar-header col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
              <b>Hello</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
               <b>Hello</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
               <b>Hello</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <b>Hello</b>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

@RenderBody()

---

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: code is pretty straight forward. I added code now

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `body` tag.

The overflow auto will add the scrollbars to the page when the content spills over the element containing it.

```
body {
    min-width: 1024px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It is becoming responsive after it fell below 990px

Comment: Can you post the CSS for your body tag please? Something must be overriding it. Does adding `!important` to the two attributes above work? If not something else is causing issues.

Comment: I dont have any special css other than bootstrap file

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways in which websites are made responsive. The solution will depend on the technique used by the library.

The simplest way is that you can add a min-width property to your css body tag like this:

```
body {
  min-width : 1024px;
}
```

But this approach won't work when the library uses @media queries. In this case you need to override those in your css. Just append an @media before your body tag.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    min-width:1024px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 990px) {
  body {
    min-width:990px;
  }
}
```

The media query adjusts the websites according to current resolution of your browser.

Comment: It is becoming responsive after it fell below 990px

Comment: can you share link of the bootstrap css/js that you have used so that i can see it?

Comment: @chatra You can add media tag for 990px as well just like for 1024px.